# How do I "select Android SDK" in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, eclipse-project-file

After a successful import of an Eclipse-Android-Project into "Android Studio 1.4", I get the error

```
"Please select Android SDK"
```

when I click on the button to run the application in the simulator, I can't find any way of doing that.

This dialog opens when I click on "run":

[image: This dialog opens up when I click on "run"]

This is the "project structure" dialog:

[image: Screenshot of the "project structure" dialog]

What should I do now?

Answer (score 2128):

I go to `build.gradle` and click **sync now**. Then it worked.

**Update** :

`File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files` **(Android Studio 3.1.1)**

`Tools` -> `Android` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files` **(Android Studio 3.0.1)**

Or You can click on the icon from the toolbar.

[image: Sync Project Icon]

> This answer may not help works for later version as Android studio Team work on making the tool more better, the way to sync may be different in the next version of Android Studio.

**COMMON WAY** that may helps is try to **sync project** and then **Invalidate Caches** and **Restart** Android Studio.

Solution for `Android Studio 3.1.2` [[See below answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50000408/5241603)

See [Latest Android Studio version](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/)

Comment: ***Android Studio 4.0.1***: File > Project structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shif+S) > Problems > Library %s is not used [Fix]

Comment: There's so much that the Android Studio developers need to automate. It's a real pain to use the IDE.

Comment: million dollar solution

Answer (score 474):

**FIX FOR 3.1.2 OR NEWER VERSIONS**

Some of my colleagues and I have faced the same issue on **AS 3.1.2**, but a simple Sync didn't help us. For us, the solution was a bit different:

1. File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate
2. File -> Close Project.
3. Remove the project from the AS project selector window.
4. Quit from Android Studio
5. Start AS and open project again

[image: reopen project instructions]

**EXTRA ADVICE IF YOU ARE FACING THIS ISSUE CONSTANTLY**

Some of you are constantly facing this issue, and this "solution" fixes it only temporarily. At the time we started getting this error, we used gradle wrapper 4.6 and Android gradle plugin 3.1.0, but since then we went back to gradle 4.4 and we use it with the latest Android gradle plugin, and we haven't seen this issue since then.

Comment: WARNING: It will delete all your shelves. Just backup those before doing this. Good solution otherwise.

Answer (score 469):

In **Android Studio 3** and above, for **Windows, Mac and Linux**:

```
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

**Solved!**

Or you can do this by **shortcut key**:

Press **⌘ + Shift + A** (*Mac*) or **Ctrl + Shift + A** (*Windows, Linux*). Then pop-up a Edit-Text and **write** `"Sync Project with Gradle Files"`. Then press double click on the option.

**Your problem is solved!** It'll sync your gradle file with your project file.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 214):

Click this icon [image] to sync `gradle`

or edit any of your module `gradle` and then sync

Answer (score 106):

Press `"Ctrl+shift+A"` and in the pop-up `EditText`, write `"Sync Project with Gradle Files"`. After that double click on the appeared option. It will then sync your `Gradle` file `SDK` with the project file.

Answer (score 76):

Just go to the **(app level)** `build.gradle` file, give an empty space somewhere and click on **sync**, once gradle shows **sync complete** then the Error will be gone

Answer (score 65):

***This is the easiest way to fix this issue:***

- **Add a comment** line to the gradle file
- It will then ask you to **Sync**.
- Click '**Sync Now**'

Viola! You're done.

Answer (score 45):

Now on Android Studio 3 and above, you can try to sync project with gradle like:

```
File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

[image]

Answer (score 44):

The menu structure and options have changed slightly as of Android 3.2.0. I fixed this error by changing the Module SDK in the following menu:

**File > Project Structure > Modules > App File > Dependencies Tab > Module SDK**

Make sure to hit **Apply** to save your changes.

[image: Modules Dependencies menu in Android Project Structure]

Comment: Fiiiiiinaly an answer other than sync gradle Thank you

Comment: olé ole. This made the trick ;)

Answer (score 38):

The comment from @Nisarg helped: "set latest version in Compile Sdk Version"

I changed from API 8 to API 23 and the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 29):

Press the first refresh button on the gradle vertical tab in Android Studio on the right

[image]

Answer (score 29):

Press " **⌘ + Shift + A**" on Mac (or "**Ctrl+Shift+A**" on Windows) and in the pop-up EditText, write "**Sync Project with Gradle Files**". After that double click on the appeared option. It will then sync your Gradle file SDK with the project file.

Answer (score 22):

**Follow these steps:**

- Goto Android Studio Settings
- Search for "Android SDK" using search bar
- Ensure the path to your android sdk folder is correct.
- After that also ensure the path is automatically updated after a prompt in your project (local.properties) file. If not, do it manually.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 22):

[image]

Go to File >> ProjectStructure(⌘;). This would open this window then select the **app** module. Then choose the Compile SDK version . Choose the latest one and click apply.

Comment: thank you for actually answering the question. all the other answers provide "solutions" but never "answer the question"

Answer (score 22):

There are multiple hit & trial solutions for this error. One of them will surely work for you.
Below are the solutions:

1.

> Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files (Android Studio
> 3.0.1)

2. 

> Go to build.gradle and click sync now

3. 

> Click hammer(Build) icon to sync Gradle
>
> or edit any of your module Gradle and then sync

4. 

> File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location Edit ->
> Android SDK

5. 

> Open build.gradle file, just add a space or press enter. Then sync
> project.

6. 

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 20):

I was having this problem on all versions of AS 3.0+. Syncing with gradle did not solve the problem for me. The solution from [András Klöczl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50000408/984830) was the only thing that would allow me to get some coding done. The problem was, anytime I had to do a gradle sync, the problem came back. So I had to go through that process any time I wanted to make a change in my `build.gradle`. What ended up working for me was to downgrade my kotlin version from `1.2.40` to `1.2.30`

Answer (score 19):

My problem was that if I changed the project (for example opened new window of Android Studio with different project) this error happened.

So I read every answer in this question and the "clear caches and open the project again" solution wasn't so useful in my case.

Instead I discovered that if the **Kotlin's plugin's version in Android Studio** was lower than in gradle file, the problem appeared.

My setup was:

- Android Studio 3.1.3
- Kotlin plugin (in Android Studio) 1.2.**30**
- Kotlin version in gradle file 1.2.**51**

---

What fixed the problem?

I updated the Kotlin plugin:

**File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install JetBrains plugin...**

Then search for Kotlin and click Update. After update just restart the Android Studio and sync Gradle.

Answer (score 16):

Just change build tools version to 25.0.3.. and sync now
I hope it will help..

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me.

File -> Settings -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Location Edit -> Android SDK

Answer (score 13):

Go to : File > Project Structure > Modules -> app > Properties

please choose :   Compile 'SDK' version = `API26`   Build Tools
 Version = 27.0.0   Source Compatibility = 1.8   Target Compatibility =
 1.8

Answer (score 11):

open build.gradle file. just add a space or press enter. then sync project. it works...

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes android studio just acts stupid and needs some kind of reset..

Go to *settings.gradle* file it should contain `include ':app'`
change it to `include ':ap'` and sync.
after sync, change it to `include ':app'` again.

It should be working OK now.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution for this problem:

First make sure your sdk path is currect.
Then
Please close current project and in android startup menu click on **import project** and choose your project from explorer.
This will always solve my problem

Answer (score 10):

If you are using 'Profile or Debug APK...', then you might come across this error.

My solution is to first check SDK for updates in SDK manager: click on "Edit" at the right side of SDK location and go through to install any updates:

[image]

Then I clicked on "Logcat" at bottom of Android Studio and find out I also need to configure Android SDK, so choose latest Android API Platform:

[image]

After that, I'm able to run the APK in Emulator.

Answer (score 9):

In my case there there is no selected java sdk version in project structure-

I had to select the -

1.Source Compatibility (1.7)

2.Target Compatibility (1.7)

as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In latest android studio 3.3.2 the icon of **`sync project with Gradle Files`** is changed

Now try this

[image]

> `File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle` Files (Android Studio 3.3.2)

Comment: Update : For Android Studio Arctic Fox, You can use same symbol for sync project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 8):

For Android Studio 3.5, "File -> Sync project with gradle files" is enough.

Answer (score 7):

Go to **gradle.build** file and click sync now
**OR**
click icon on **Sync project with Gradle file**

**OR**
Go to **Tools**-> **Android** -> **Sync project with Gradle file**

Answer (score 7):

If your android SDK path is given and still you facing this issue then it might because your android studio not synced well, even you have clicked on "**Sync now**" link.

So for re sync it go to **app gradle** file and make any change or just give a space and now sync again. It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I downloaded a git repository for an android project. The project required minimum sdk version 21 and target sdk version 27. When I tried to run the project it gave me "Please select Android SDK error". I checked that I had already downloaded the required sdk files.

For me the solution was to "sync project with Gradle Files"
[image]

Answer (score 7):

It helped me:

```
1. close project
2. remove .idea/ folder
3. select "import project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)"
```

Environment:

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
OS Macos High Sierra 10.13.5
```

Another answers don't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

After opening my project in Android Studio, I opened the App version of the build.gradle file, located in the Gradle Scripts folder of the Project.  When I hovered my mouse pointer over the buildToolsVersion number, a tooltip popped, indicating that the version of Android Build Tools needed to be upgraded (see screenshot). I changed the value of the buildToolsVersion to the one identified by the error (27.0.2) and the problem was solved.  The original error (Please select Android SDK) went away and the project compiled successfully, again.  Although this solution was mentioned previously, the exact steps seemed to be missing, so hopefully this clears up any doubt.  I guess the root cause for this problem is that a new version of the build tools were released but Android Studio did not trigger any notification to me, which would have indicated that I should manually fix this (since Android Studio does not seeem to have the ability to upgrade this build.gradle file internally), which leaves the onus on the user to find the problem and fix it.[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had to bump kotlin version down to 1.2.31 from 1.2.41 for the run to be enabled.
my environment:
macOS - 10.13.4 (high sierra)
AS version - 3.1.3

Answer (score 4):

MY SOLUTION
This bug drove me crazy. No amount of syncing fixed it. I found that if I modified my module's build.gradle (by maybe adding a blank line or a space after a line), and then syncing that file, all is good.

Answer (score 3):

You have to Select Build Tool Version from your project setting.

1. Select Project App Folder
2. Press F4 OR Right Click on Project App
   Folder and open Module Settings In The Properties tab select Build
   Tool Version from List

This will work on my side i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I reimported the project and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I get this error on Android Studio 4.0.1. Here is my solution: Go your build.gradle(Module: app) file and then update compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just change the minSdKversion to 23 like:

```
andriod {
    compileSdKVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
          minSdKversion 23
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem solved by setting NDK path in Android Studio.

File-> Project Structure->NDK Location.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click the File menu from the android studio.

File -> Settings -> System Settings -> Android SDK

[image: File -> Settings -> System Settings -> Android SDK]

Answer (score 1):

You are using Google API SDK. This for some reason doesn't work anymore with the embedded java JDK / JRE.

Follow the solution I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34397118/failed-to-set-up-sdk-errormodule-app-platform-google-inc-google-apis21/40242661#40242661) and set Android Studio JDK path to your local JDK (ex. OpenJDK)

Answer (score 1):

There're bunch of answers, I tried to use one of those solutions by adding new line in build.gradle file, but it didn't work. Then I changed comileSdkVersion to another version and then changing it back to version I had. "Sync" button appeared. Pressing it, solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. I tried sync with gradle files and removed .idea folder but nothing works.

Here is what worked for me :

> 1.) Close android studio
>
> 2.) Remove c:/Users/{User}/.AndroidStudio{version} folder

Caution: It will remove all your installed plugins and settings. 
Try this if nothing works

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with Android Studio 3.1.3:

1. Open your problematic project in Android Studio. Click **File > Export to Zip File**.
2. Close your problematic project (**Exit** Android Studio if necessary).
3. In your OS, Delete your problematic project folder. Then extract the zip you just made previously.
4. Back to Android Studio. On startup screen, click "**Open an existing Android Project**".  Browse to the folder you just extracted.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

***buildToolsVersion*** might be missing in your app's build.gradle

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
```

Add it like this [image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a double declaration of a dependency inside the project level build.gradle. Once I removed it, did a Gradle sync and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Work for me `1 File > close preject.  2 open an existing Android Studio project`

Answer (score 1):

MY SOLUTION
This bug drove me crazy. No amount of syncing fixed it. I found that if I modified my module's build.gradle in AndroidStudio (by maybe adding a blank line or a space after a line), and then syncing that file, all is good.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are suffering from this problem, I suggest you do a clean install ( delete any existing settings and files of prior installations ). Don't waste time fixing the problem. I am searching for the answer for android studio 3.6.3 with no result.

Answer (score 1):

Sync  didn't help me. Neither helped invalidating cache.
I simply removed and cloned again the repository and it worked:

1. Make sure you have no uncommitted changes
2. Sync your local repository with remote github
3. Delete folder with the local repository
4. Clone the repository from github to local again
5. Open the cloned repository in the Android Studio
6. Build and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

The project depends on an SDK, and there is none.
Go to File -> Project Structure (Edited: I said Settings before)
Select Modules, and go to the Dependencies tab
Likely you will see No SDK in the Export column.
Choose one from the Module SDK dropdown, or create a new one if the list is empty.
No SDK should now update to the selected SDK.
It should work then... Hopefully. :)
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the Android SDK in Android Studio is a crucial step when developing Android applications. Here are the step-by-step instructions on how to do it:

1.Open Android Studio

2.Just click file and click on project structure

[image: project structure]

3.And then you can click modules and then you can show compile sdk version you can chaing it you can select Compile sdk version

[image: Sdk Version]

4.You can also chaing Target sdk version

[image: Target sdk version]

5.Sync Project & Rebuild project Again.

Answer (score 0):

Source Compatibility should be selected as the minimum Android Version that your app should be compatible with(usually selected as SDK 15), Target Compatibility should be selected as the newest Android Version that your app should be compatible with(SDK 23). 
Afterwards you want to check your AndroidMenifest and your gradle.build to see if its realy set to the properties selected if not you can just add it manually. and ofcourse you should check the SDK Location is actually pointing to your android studio SDK folder (if you are importing from Eclipse then you should point to your Eclipse SDK folder).

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

Build --> Make Project

It's worked for me.

Answer (score -6):

Give SDK path in local.properties file as

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\System43\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

and give latest version in compilesdk in gradle file.

Comment: Please explain answer properly