# Error: Please select Android SDK

Tags: android

My Android Studio version is 2.1 preview.
I'm running my project using Google APIs, Android 17, rev 4 (API 17).

I'm having 1 pop-up error while debugging app.

```
[Information: Image to show my pop-up errror. Click to show this.][1]
```

I never met error like this earlier.
How can I resolve this?

Updated:

I often meet error like this:

```
error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator
```

I waas trying to do research on this. I tried but it never worked out. When does this error come and how can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Android Studio preference-> search for "SDK" -> edit Android SDK Location point it to your sdk android folder.

**UPDATE**

For resolve this error

```
error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator
```

Download jdk 1.7 and open Module Setting -> SDK Location -> edit JDK Location point it to jdk 1.7 home foler.

Comment: sorry, I can't add a new question in 90 minutes. You can look my question update. I usually meet this error but I don't know how to resolve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Luna Open your Module Setting edit JDK location change to use java 1.7 instead of 1.6

Comment: You awesome. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 20):

It is not an error. Its just Android Studio trying to figure out what you want to debug. So in your case the "app" module. Have you done a gradle build through? Pushing this: [image]. Gradle should set it up so you dont have to choose debug target.

**EDIT:** This icon is different on Android Studio 3.0, is called "Sync Project with Gradle Files".

Comment: I clicked your icon. But it also shows like http://i.imgur.com/SMHQ5I7.png
The icon x red in-app => I can debug.

Comment: this helped, after gradle sync AS finally start working and fetched android sdk

Comment: This icon is different on Android Studio 3.0, is called "Sync Project with Gradle Files". Great answer!

Answer (score 5):

Go to

> Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

in Android Studio 3.0.1  to solve the following

> Error: Please select Android SDK

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40356815/5706413)

Answer (score 4):

On new Android Studio;
Open app's module settings with right click,
Select 'app' from left sidebar,
Change 'Compile Sdk Version' na 'Build Tools Version' as whatever your compileSdkVersion & buildToolsVersion are on build.gradle,
Click OK, that's it.