# Continuing problems with Android Studio not finding Android SDK

Tags: android-studio, sdk, installation, windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise, and I just downloaded Android Studio and did the standard install. I have an APK that I wanted to work with--actually I first wanted to emulate it and display it to an audience. However, when I tried to Run the app, I got "missing JDK", so I downloaded OpenJDK and put it in my user data folder for Android Studio and directed it, then I got "Error please select Android SDK"

In the Project Structure I have Android API 28 Platform, but it still says "No SDK". Basic question: Is that the SDK? I have tried every variant of the advice for Windows in this old thread, [Android Studio: "Please select Android SDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk) but nothing seems to work.

Why is this a perennial issue? What can I do?
Thank you for your help!
[The menu with location of Android API 28 Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUV2A.jpg)
[The project menu showing "No SDK" and the API 28 Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqLMX.jpg)