# Cannot access class 'android.content.Intent'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

- I have created one new project in Android Studio but getting error regarding `Intent` class:
- I have already tried **`Invalidate Caches -> Restart, clean build & restart`** - everything but still not working!

[image]

Comment: try solution from [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020552/not-resolving-importing-any-class-android-studio).

Comment: show your both build.gradle files