# Android Studio Gradle adding Gson: Unresolved Reference / Please select Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gson

I add Gson to my gradle dependencies and nearly all dependencies stop to resolve. (additionally I get the "Error: Please select Android SDK"-Error)
I know this a well known bug and I can solve it as described in this post.

I took like 3 tries with different versions, but i just not works.

[Android Studio: "Please select Android SDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk/50000408#50000408)

**Any hints why Gson makes here trouble?**

(I'm using Kotlin.)

**My Android Studio:**

```
> Android Studio 3.1.2 Build #AI-173.4720617, built on April 13, 2018
> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
> JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0
```

**Relevant gradle.build snippet**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.23.4'
// -erro- implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:+"
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not recommended to use the latest version (+), use this instead:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```