# Error : Please select Android SDK

Tags: android, select, sdk

Here is the case, we pulled the project from Github, and when we try to add Firebase FCM, or Service Files, this SDK problem occurs:

[image]

We've checked the SDK path, tried 'Sync Project with Gradle Files', and 'invalidate cashes / restart' but then still it doesn't work...

This is the developing environment from the fore developers

> Android Studio : Android Studio 3.3 Preview
>   jdk : java version "1.8.0_171" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
>   OS : macOS High Sierra 10.13.5
>   Kotlin : 1.2.50 
>   gradle : 3.3.0-alpha03

This is my developing environment

> Android Studio : Android Studio 3.1.3
>   jdk : java version "1.8.0_1.8.1"
>   OS : Windows 10
>   kotlin : ?
>   gradle : 3.3.0-alpha03

Comment: please check this and let me know:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk/50000408#50000408)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

Comment: check environment paths and restart PC

Comment: Run this: "File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files" and will solve it