# Design layout preview isn't loading in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android

Android resource linking failed
Output:

```
D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:461: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:462: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\KAMAL\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\1004f9e02d2cf44b39e5208f3f298ce2\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\KAMAL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.mmc.getdevicelocation2\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        xxhdpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        D:\GetDeviceLocation2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

[image]

Comment: check your mainfest, maybe there are some errors there.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Top Heading is my question - Design layout preview isn't loading in Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: A lot of efforts exhausted me then finally below steps solved my problem:

Clear caches folder from C:/Users//.grade/caches
Clear caches folder from C:/Users//.AndroidStuido3.x/system/caches
Restart Android Studio
Clean build project
After hours of experimenting and going through lots of solutions, this was the one that actually worked.

Hope anyone in the future faces this problem will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Goto "Build" tab bar android studio . click build after  Clean and Rebuild  project.

Comment: I've done this before but the error is same.

Answer (score 0):

1- In your module gradle file

```
buildToolsVersion **'28.0.3'**
compileSdkVersion **28**
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion **28**
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1.0"
    multiDexEnabled false
}
```

if you use other modules inside project make sure that compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion versions are all the same. (28.x.x)

2-This happens when there is an unsuccessful gradle build. See this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk/49117948#49117948)

3-Another solution is: In the menu

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

you need to press `Invalidate and Restart` button. This helps in many situations especially if you pull changes from a git repository and if someone changed libraries at the gradle files.

Comment: Solution #1 worked but the design pallets are not loading in the preview still.

Comment: Still the problem is unsolved. Can anyone help me out in this ?

Comment: open application manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) you will see two tabs below the code. Click on merged manifest. tell us what is writing there.

Comment: not screenshot just copy paste the text here

Comment: see, the code is not getting copied too.

Comment: I'm having less chars to paste the code text here.