# Android Studio 3.1.2 constantly shows error "Please select Android SDK"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1.3

Periodically, Android Studio shows error

```
 Error: Please select Android SDK
```

in edit configuration.

**Gradle version:** 4.10.2

Following things don't help:

- Sync Project with Gradle Files
- Invalidate Caches and Restart

I understand this question is similar to [Android Studio: "Please select Android SDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk)
but this question is specific for Android Studio version 3.1.2+

In the above question, comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/50000408/ solves issue temporarily but no such robust solution.

Does anyone face this issue?

Comment: Can you follow @Andras Kloczl answer in this link??. [Android Studio: “Please select Android SDK”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk)

Comment: I have already linked that answer in the description, it's a temporary solution. I do that whenever this problem occurs. But it comes constantly. I lose all my shelves and project settings

Comment: how about your `local.peroperties`? is the `sdk.dir` properly set?

Comment: Yeah, it is properly set. This error is just random, comes out of nowhere every morning. And I have to close project everyday

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue too. I fixed it by updating Android studio so that it matches the gradle build tools version.

This version number:

[image: Gradle build tools version number]

needs to match this version number:

[image: Android Studio version number]

Comment: I found that simply upgrading A.S. did it for me even though my gradle build version is `3.3.0` and does not match the `3.4.1` of the A.S. upgrade. So I'm guessing A.S. >= gradle in general could work.