# Please select Android SDK - error message

Tags: java, android

My project worked as well. but when I Installed kotlin I got this error message:

```
Please select Android SDK
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: related [Android Studio: “Please select Android SDK”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34353220/7666442)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: "Please select Android SDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk)

Comment: but I have the same error: `Gradle build finished in 2s 284ms`