# Could not Resolve Symbol R After Migrating to Androidx

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

After migrating to Androidx,my project start displaying a red underline error which says could not resolve R.

1. i have Tried googling for some similar issue but yet the error
   remain,
2. i have checked my manifest, my Res folder for error
3. i have novalidate/restart project
4. i have clean and rebuild project
5. i have sync gradle with android project

yet after i have done these, the error still remains

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'


    implementation 'com.github.maxyou:CalendarPicker:v1.1.2'

//    Ramotion
    implementation 'com.ramotion.paperonboarding:paper-onboarding:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.ramotion.garlandview:garland-view:0.3.3'
}
```

MyApplication.java

````
package xyz.esusku.nearbyworker;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}```
````

Comment: i have even create a new project and yet the problem remains

Comment: i have just import the project, and yet error remains

Comment: One (or more) of your layouts still reference the older AppCompat dependencies in xml. That is why the R file generation is failing.

Comment: @Zionnite what IDE version do you use? Try the latest one for IntelliJ IDEA and RC for AS.

Comment: @farhanjk, pls how can i search for the older AppCompat??

Comment: Look for obvious stuff like `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` has changed to `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`. Any fully qualified name in your layout.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, am downloading a newer version of Intellij IDEA now

Comment: @farhanjk, ok let me also start checking

Comment: @farhanjk, it just a new project, i only have just one xml file which is the one created by the IDE Wiszard and search through there is only one element which is the The TextView

Comment: Hmmm, well it was worth checking as I have faced the issue before. Sorry my friend, let's wait for smarter people to solve this one.

Comment: @farhanjk,  ok thanks for you time

Comment: Can you include your Android Studio version and grad;e version in the question?

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf, follow this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://twitter.com/tasomaniac/status/1103020923874131968 for the details.

Gradle Android Plugin 3.3+ no longer generates R source file. You either need to update to the IDE that supports the new binary format for the resources or downgrade the plug-in to an older version in your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have added these line in  *gradle.properties file:* as you are trying to migrate existing project.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

one more thing try removing the duplicate import-

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; //remove this line
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Comment: i have done that exactly but yet the error still persist

Comment: i tried `import android.R` it work by eliminating the error but it does not open layout folder