# AndroidStudio and Kotlin Cannot access 'android.app.Activity'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Recently I was forced to do a fresh install of Ubuntu.  I had copied all my AndroidStudio projects that I was creating in the tutorial, to a flash drive and added them to the the new OS setup. On both systems they were/are in a dir/ AndroidStudioProjects.

Maybe installing Android Studio on the new OS gave me a new version of it.  The current version I am using is `4.1.1` I've worked through a couple of problems but this one is stumping me.  I'm not seeing any help on Google threads that is pointing me in the right direction.

Here is my MainActivity.kt file:

```
package com.johndcowan.cardviewlayout

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout)
    }
}
```

The class section is all underlined with the red-squiggly line.  The error, when I hover, is:

```
Cannot access 'android.app.Activity' which is a supertype of 'com.johndcowan.cardviewlayout.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

When I hover over the `Bundle` line, I get this error:

```
value-parameter savedInstanceState: [ERROR : Bundle]?
```

I noticed that in the configure Android SDK, I see the Android SDK location is:

```
/home/jdc44/Android/Sdk
```

I'm assuming this is correct. That path exists with subdirectories, but it does not point to any specific file. (??)

Comment: Do you have the android jar in the `sdk/platorms/android-version`?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  What is the full path to ... sdk/platforms/android-version?  I do not know where to look to see that.  Sorry!

Comment: I think this fixed it for me.  I found this thread in StackOverFlow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/how-do-i-select-android-sdk-in-android-studio  answer #439.  Menu: File >> Sync Project with Gradle Files.  app is working again.  Yay!

Comment: Just so you know, any time you make a change in your ``build.gradle`` files, you have to sync it - it pops up a little "sync now" option at the top, you pretty much always want to hit that!

Answer (score 0):

When you start a new project check the legacy android.support libraries checkbox.
and thats it :)