# Android Studio project files are so large and taking too long to sync from OneDrive. Are there essential files to download instead?

Tags: android, android-studio, onedrive

I am trying to restore my Android Studio project file from One Drive. It is taking so long, the files are so huge and I am worried why this is so. I have used eclipse, swift and it is not this complicated.

Any ideas on which files are most important that I can download and continue working? This is happening because my development laptop developed a fault right in the middle of a project so I hopped on another computer to sync from OneDrive and continue my project development. I would usually do this on Eclipse and it takes a little time.

But, this is 12 hours. I am still waiting. Presently, all the files are synced to the local OneDrive except this 'build folder'. It is still syncing.
[OneDrive infinite Sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVNSO.png)

Trying to get Android Studio to open the project anyway was not possible. It's stuck on 'indexing'. I decided to download the build folder manually from the web Onedrive because it indicated 63.8kb... Well, this is one hour the supposedly tiny file is still downloading 'infinitely' now at 128mb!
[manual download of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxLgA.png)
Can anyone help me out here? How can I get my project up and running again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to the problem here > [Files that can be safely removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902142/reduce-android-studio-project-size)
According to @fweigl in the link above, the entire build folder can be excluded, it would be regenerated by Android Studio. I made the costly mistake of waiting for all the files in my Project Files to sync and then tried to import my project from the OneDrive costing hours of waiting.
It is important to also delete the .idea folder and the .iml file if you do not want to get some build errors.

Comment: I am still curious as to why Android Studio project files have to be so large. Mine was over 500mb for a single project!